# erro with install psycopg2 on windows

Tags: python, c++, windows

i get the down below error while i want to install psycopg2 with pip install on windows with python 3.9

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\mohammadmilad\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c    'import sys, setuptools,
```

Answer (score 0):

**first step**     download a version of psycopg2
**second step**   `pip install pipwin`
then              `pipwin install psycopg2`            and end